# How do I avoid global variables when using MQTT callbacks

Tags: python, callback, mqtt, global, paho

I am incrementing a global variable in my on_receive callback, to track how many messages have been received.  I need to know this count for testing purposes.

Since global variables are generally considered a code smell, is there a way to avoid using global variables in this situation?

Here is my callback:

```
def on_message_callback_v3( message_client, userdata, message ):
  global global_message_received_count
  with my_mutex:
    global_message_received_count += 1
    msg = str( message.payload.decode( "utf-8" ) )
    print( f"▼▼ ON MESSAGE ▼▼" )
    print( f"  Message received for client: {message_client}" )
    print( f"  Message user data: {userdata}" )
    print( f"  Message topic: {message.topic}" )
    print( f"  Message body: {msg}" )
```

When all messages have been published, I compare `global_message_received_count` to the `published_count` (incremented elsewhere), to determine if all messages have been received.  Since the signature of the callback is enforced by Paho, I cannot pass in or return variables.

I would like to avoid replying on the global `global_message_received_count`.

Comment: please provide your implementation, so we can help with the task at hand.

Comment: What problem do you have with using a global variable?

Comment: @hardillb I have no problem using global variables.  It's just that they are generally considered a code smell, and I would like to know if I'm overlooking some technique.

Comment: @AdamHowell there probably is a pretty simple solution. But without knowing, how your code looks like, we can not give it to you.

Comment: @JeanotZubler I included the callback.  Should I include other code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be to use a class / object that handles receiving messages. That way, the count can be a property of the handler object (code simplified):

```py
class MessageReceivedHandler:
    count = 0
      
    def on_message_callback(self, message_client, userdata, message):
        self.count += 1
        print(message)
```

You can then create an instance of the handler: `handler = MessageReceivedHandler()` and pass `handler.on_message_callback` as the callback. The `handler.count` variable can then be accessed to check the amount of received messages.